# MySQL Group BY, Having, Order By Query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, having

Ok, so assume I have the following tables:

**recipes**

```
id (pk)
name
added
modified
```

**recipe_versions**

```
id (pk)
recipe_id (fk to recipes.id)
version
content
added
```

What I want is a query that grabs the latest `recipe_versions.added` data and then joins with the base `recipe` data. Then sorts all results by `recipes.added ASC` I have the following, but the group by, is not selecting the latest recipe_versions row, seems to be selecting the first.

```
SELECT r.`id`,
      r.name,
      rv.version,
      rv.content,
      r.added,
      r.modified,
 FROM recipes r,
      recipe_versions rv
WHERE r.`id` = rv.recipe
GROUP BY rv.recipe
HAVING max(rv.added) 
ORDER BY r.added ASC
```

Comment: Is `id` in the `recipe_versions` table a unique autoincrementing int? If so, would you think the latest `added` would be in correspondence with the latest `id` per `recipe_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT
    c.*, b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT recipe_id, MAX(added) AS mostrecent
        FROM recipe_versions
        GROUP BY recipe_id
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    recipe_versions b ON 
        a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id AND
        a.mostrecent = b.added
INNER JOIN
    recipes c ON a.recipe_id = c.id
ORDER BY
    c.added
```

Comment: Yikes, I gotta try and figure this out. Let me try it.